# How to move a div inside a table cell to another cell vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a div inside a cell. From the example code below, it is initially positioned on cell (1,1). Now, I want it to move to other cells inside the table on mouse drag. Here is my code.

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <td v-for="col in cols">
            <div class="ball" v-if="col == 1 && row == 1"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
  export default{
  data() {
    return{
       cols: 10,
       rows: 10,
    }
   }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .ball{ 
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    background:blue; 
  }
  td{ 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

How could I move it on specific cell using vuejs?

https://jsfiddle.net/cmvn2yda/

Comment: You can use the excellent Vue-Dragula - https://github.com/kristianmandrup/vue2-dragula

Comment: @IVOGELOV, thanks for the link but I guess this doesn't drag and drop the item.

Comment: Dragula drags and drops any DOM node and Vue-Dragula wraps the original `plain vanilla JavaScript` Dragula as a standard Vue directive so you can use it with groups of items - but this does not mean you can not drag/drop just a single element.